# how to insert values into an amazon rds using python boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-rds, boto

I am trying to get common prefixes from an amazon s3 bucketthrough python

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
result = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket.name, Delimiter='/')
for o in result.get('CommonPrefixes'):
    print(o.get('Prefix'))
```

and now I want to insert these prefixes into an Amazon RDS MySQL database. I have a table bucket in which there are column `bucket_id` , `prefixes`. I want to store this result into the database inside the bucket table:

```
username:<myusername>
password:<mypassword>
 url :environment-instance.cg3tbe50l9yn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306

database:<my-database>
tablename:<bucket>
columnName:<name>
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you asking how to store data in a database? You could use an SQL `INSERT` statement. Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details of what you are wanting to do, what you have tried so far and what difficulties you have encountered.

Comment: Thanks ,  I have edited the question , I just don't want to run the scripts manually , I want that whenever I fetch any value from s3 ,it gets inserted into a particular column

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch any value"? How are you doing this? Amazon S3 is an object-storage system that stores files, note values. Or are you referring to Amazon S3 Select?

Comment: Sorry , by fectching any value means here like inside any s3 bucket i have object/files for which i am fetching the common prefixes and last modified date

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still cannot understand what you are doing. I suggest that you Edit your question and try to explain exactly what you are doing (supply code if possible) and what difficulties you are encountering. Please include details like what language you are using and each step that the program is doing.

Comment: Edited , hope it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188783/discussion-between-vatsal-rahul-and-john-rotenstein).